# How to display a value stored into a string(java) in angular 8?

Tags: java, mysql, angular, angular8

I am new in angular 8. I have a java project using JDBC to connect to **MySQL**.
I have some values stored in MySQL table which are accessed in **java** and stored in strings (or a list) , now i want to display the contents of the strings in a table format in **angular 8** from java. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This questions is misleading, as angular8 is a javascript framework, and has nothing to do with java. Probably you want to access from angula (javascript) to the date accessed by java, in this case you need to make your java application to provide an API, to be consumed by your javascript fronten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are talking about your back-end Java+JDBC. Angular being a front-end framework requires you to make an API call to your Java server to fetch these values. Typically you would make an API call from your Angular code to your server to retrieve your values. The server can either serve JSON or a Java Bean wrapped in the ResponseEntity object, which Angular will know how to parse e.g.

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(new MyOwnClassWithSomeData());
```

For the back-end you may wish to use frameworks such as Spring Boot and there is plenty of advice online (videos or text tutorials) taking you step by step through writing your first Angular + Spring Boot Hello World application.